# Iterating through tables in map document and replacing workspace paths using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, arcgis-10.4

I am using Python 2.7 and ArcGIS 10.4.1 to create a script that walks through folders and scans for mxds. I use a set to get unique data sources and copy the data to a new folder keeping the same data format. I would then like to access the map document and repath all layers and tables to the copied data. I'm struggling to get the tables repathing code to work. In the below example, I have a fGDB table in the mxd and have copied the fGDB that it sits in to a new folder. I would thus like to repath to the table in the copied fGDB.

```
import arcpy, os
mxdrep = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dfsrep = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxdrep)

ignoreStringList = ["Vendor", "vendor", ".sde"]
#Target folder containing the copied fGDB
dbFolder = os.path.join(projFolderPath, "Databases")
for dfrep in dfsrep:
   tablesRep = arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxdrep, "", dfrep)
   tabRepDataSrc = tableRep.dataSource
   #Excludes data sources containing list of sub strings
   if not any(folders in tabRepDataSrc for folders in ignoreStringList):
      #Create the table view for each table
      tableRepView = arcpy.mapping.TableView(tabRepDataSrc)
      # Get the directory level to replace
      tabPath = os.path.dirname(tabRepDataSrc)
      tabRepPath = os.path.dirname(tabPath)
      #Repath the tables
      tableRepView.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(tabRepPath, dbFolder)
```

This gives a rather cryptic error;

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 182, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\_mapping.py", line 1284, in findAndReplaceWorkspacePath
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(*gp_fixargs((find_workspace_path, replace_workspace_path, validate), True)))
ValueError: Layer: Unexpected error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I was actually creating a table view of a table view. The corrected code reads:

```
import arcpy, os
mxdrep = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dfsrep = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxdrep)

#Target folder containing the copied fGDB
dbFolder = os.path.join(projFolderPath, "Databases")
for dfrep in dfsrep:
   tablesRep = arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxdrep, "", dfrep)
   for tableRep in tablesRep:
      tabDirPath = tableRep.workspacePath
      #Excludes data sources containing list of sub strings
      if not ".sde" in tabDirPath:
         tabWsPath = os.path.dirname(tabDirPath)
         tableRep.findAndReplaceWorkspacePath(str(tabWsPath), dbFolder)
mxdrep.save()
del mxdrep
```

Answer (score -1):

I have both a C# compiled version and original code of a couple Addin for Arc Catalog that do this task . in a zipped format but where do I host it for you. (newbie life)

Comment: https://preview.tinyurl.com/y7ujgpga

Comment: Thanks Mat. I need to embed it as part of a larger copy script so just after some help with the code for replacing the table paths. I can’t seem to find any examples even on the Esri pages.

Comment: Just a thought.  I dont know enough about coding , but I would have thought you could call the C# addin app from within the script if it was exposed in such a way that python could find and run it. albeit the addin requires some user input too. I cant recall where the original code came from but I am sure parts of it was on the edn at one stage.